# Stars twinkling

Tags: planetary-science

What is the science behind the vigorous glow of stars ? Since 2 days I was observing one of the stars in blue and red colour I just want to know what is the speciality of that star?

Comment: This question is not about earth sciences - it is about actual intrinsic star colors (your title says 'twinkling' but your text does not), and belongs on [astronomy.se]. There are already some questions over there about [star color](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+star+color) but yours seems not to have been asked yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about earth or other planets. It belongs on Astronomy.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Stars do have different colors depending of their temperature,
- different intensities depending of their size, temperature and distance,
- twinkle is due to turbulence in the atmosphere (you don't have it in space).
- the glow you might see is a effect in your telescope, camera or eye. It has several components due to the opening size, imperfect lense, and captors.